# How do I capture actual screen data instead of monitor screenshots?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Context**
For a little while I've been looking for a solution on how to get around the WinAPI monitor refresh rate limit built into `mss` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075238/mss-capture-rate-limited-by-ctypes-in-python-how-do-i-fix-this)).

**The Problem**
Is there a better python library than `mss` that, instead of capturing an image of what is on the monitor, can capture the color of every pixel being sent to the monitor from my computer *before* it gets there? Data might only be sent to the monitor to be displayed every 1/60th of a second, but is there a way to get that data more often? Like a fake or virtual monitor that runs at higher framerates then what can be displayed, maybe?

**Edit 1**
The goal here is to capture the RGB values of specific pixels at a rate >240 fps without having a monitor that refreshes that fast.

Comment: I think a problem here is that things aren't going to change on the screen, virtual or not, between the frames. Basically all good programs will cap their visual refresh rate. What is the actual information you hope to retrieve from the screen?

Comment: @LukeBorowy I intend to set a cap on mine too, I just need it to run at about 240-300 fps. I'm looking for the colors of certain pixels on the screen. It should be noted that reducing the bounding box `bbox` does not allow me to capture any faster due to the limitations.

Comment: I meant the programs you are trying to capture from have caps set. The rgb values of the pixels on screen are presumably being updated by some program which has a cap set. You are stuck with whatever framerate that program wants to update its pixels at.

Comment: @LukeBorowy Got it, is there any way to get around that? Maybe another python library that you know about?

Comment: It all depends on the program you are looking at. Maybe it has an API or alternate way to get data besides the screen. Python won't be able to reprogram the way a different software works. What is the program?

Comment: @LukeBorowy I'm assuming when you're referring to the program you mean where the `mss` library is getting used? If not I don't understand. Assuming that is it, though, I can't go into too much detail about it, but essentially what it does is it repeatedly takes screenshots within a certain area, checks the colors of 8 pixels on the screen, and does stuff based on the RGB values of those pixels.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the program that is producing the pixels on the screen. Is it google chrome, a video game, or microsoft word, etc? That is the original source of the pixels, and you can't force it to put pixels on your <monitor or virtual display> faster than it wants to. Those 8 pixels you are interested in have to come from somewhere.

Comment: @LukeBorowy I see, thanks for clarifying. There is a couple of applications that I need to capture pixels from, I was hoping addressing one would solve them all but that is not the case. I've been testing with Opera GX, though I believe the owner of the computer the program is intended for will be using it on Microsoft edge. I have a separate, personal use for this where it will be running in Minecraft and Factorio, and Roblox. Minecraft usually runs >60 fps, Factorio at 60 fps, and I'm not sure about Roblox. I see how this could be a problem I can't solve.

Comment: Yeah, I think you now see the problem. Factorio is hard capped at 60. Your computer probably can't run Minecraft or Roblox at 240hz. And the website you are visiting using Edge or Opera probably can't update that fast either. If it is a video game, it will be limited by the graphics card. If it is something like a youtube video, it is limited by the video file. The only potential "ultra-high fps" thing you could get is an extremely smooth loading circle animation on a website, if you did manage to get Edge to update a (virtual) monitor that quickly.

Comment: You are going to have to use a different approach to acquire the information that those pixels give you. Because really, you are reading the pixels in an attempt to understand some sort of output. Getting the output a different way would be faster. Factorio and Minecraft both have modding APIs you could use to get game information. Creating a userscript (a piece of javascript that runs on the website just for you) might get you faster information from your Edge or Opera usecase.

Comment: @LukeBorowy All of that is probably out of my scope of knowledge. I will look into the modding APIs but I know nothing about js, though I appreciate the advice.